# Dropdown menu inside of another drop down menu is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble getting a drop-down menu inside another dropdown menu to work. The first level dropdown works fine, but for the second level, when I click on the option for the dropdown menu (Learning Profiles) nothing happens... the menu fails to display.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <nav id="sideNavBar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li id="navBarTitle">MENU</li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="Children.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="droptown-toggle">Children <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="ChildrenAddChild.html">Add Child</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ChildrenAddChild.html">Archive/Delete Child</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ChildrenDetails.html">Children Details</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="ChildrenProfiles.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="droptown-toggle">Learning Profiles<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="Observations.html">Observations</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="learningOutcomes.html">Learning Outcomes</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="Photos.html">Photos</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I found this link which might help you: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: Since the Bootstrap documentation doesn't mention that nested dropdowns aren't supported, I assumed that they were. But you could be right and maybe they aren't supported. The link you sent me shows exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I'll check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Another good link - http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is little change in the html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <nav id="sideNavBar">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li id="navBarTitle">MENU</li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="Children.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="droptown-toggle">Children <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="ChildrenAddChild.html">Add Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="ChildrenAddChild.html">Archive/Delete Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="ChildrenDetails.html">Children Details</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class ="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#" class="test droptown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Learning Profiles<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li>
                                          <a href="Observations.html">Observations</a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a href="learningOutcomes.html">Learning Outcomes</a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a href="Photos.html">Photos</a>
                                      </li>
                                  </ul>
                               </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </nav>
       </div>
  </div>
```

and add the following css

```
   .dropdown-submenu {
     position: relative;
    }
   .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
   }
```

also you need to add javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
 $(this).next('ul').toggle();
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

working plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/jjrowMvX3FJ7OAsFpiaA?p=preview